# Create index of a JSON property

Tags: sql, db2

My PHP app creates logs with Monolog and stores the logs on an IBM i DB2 database (version 7.4). Each log entry is stored as JSON in a `varchar(20000)` column.

I am able to access any given value, such as the referring url, when I use

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(COLUMN_NAME, '$.extra.referrer') 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

But if I try to search the json

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(COLUMN_NAME, '$.extra.referrer') = 'http://example.com'
```

it's *incredibly* slow (it takes minutes). I assume it's due to a lack of having a suitable index.

My question is: how do I create an index on `$.extra.referrer`?

I got so desperate I even asked Bing's AI, which gave me an answer that didn't work when I replaced `index_name`, `table_name`, `json_field`, and `property_name`:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name (JSON_VALUE(json_field, '$.property_name'));
```

Results in this error:

> [Code: -356, SQL State: 429BX]  [SQL0356] Index expression 1 not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the best solution would be to have a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the table.

This trigger could use `JSON_VALUE(COLUMN_NAME, '$.extra.referrer')` to extract the values of interest from the doc into a separate set of columns.  Then you can simply create an index on the new column(s).

That assumes that Monolog doesn't have an issue with the extra columns.  If it does, you could simply extract the values into columns in a new table along with whatever is used a a PK in the Monolog table.

**EDIT**
I ran across a [presentation about Db2 Cloud (pp58-60)](https://www.tridex.org/wp-content/uploads/Db2-JSON-Features-TRIDEX.pdf) that suggested storing BSON provides for faster processing.

> Performance: Storage Format
>
> - Db2 uses the BSON format internally for the processing done by the JSON access functions
> - The BSON format has the advantage of having already parsed the document into key:value pairs as well as having a tree structure
>   available for easy traversal
> - JSON documents need to be converted internally to BSON to allow the Db2 functions to be able traverse them
> - Any data stored in JSON format that is accessed by these functions is first implicitly converted to BSON format and any result returned
>   is converted back to JSON format (if this is requested)
> - This overhead occurs for each unique access to the JSON data and can significantly impact the performance of a query

And the [IBM i docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=data-json-concepts) mention

> BSON is a standardized binary representation format for serializing
> JSON text. It allows for fast traversal of JSON.

So if you can insert BSON instead of JSON, you'll likely get better performance.  How much, I'm not sure.  Likely not enough if you're always doing a full table scan.  But if you've got a Timestamp column of log date and can restrict to set periods, it might be enough.

Note that the conversion to BSON would add overhead to the inserts, but it's probably worthwhile.

And be sure you understand `allocate-clause` for your varchar/varbinary columns.  Normally you'd want allocate enough space inline such that 80% or so of your values fit in the table space rather than the overflow space.  When the Db2 has to read from the overflow space in addition to the table space, it takes an extra I/O.
The default allocation for any variable length field over 32(?) bytes is 0.

Comment: Ouch, I wasn’t aware of those last 3 bullet points; that sounds significant as the table gets larger. My reasoning for not using bson (readability) was apparently quite shortsighted…